# 1D weighted Isotonic Regression (PAV): a simple description of the algorithm

Tags: regression, isotonic

I have to use [IsotonicRegression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.isotonic.IsotonicRegression.html#sklearn.isotonic.IsotonicRegression) class from [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html) with non-uniform point weights: in method `IsotonicRegression.fit` parameter `sample_weight!=None`.

I roughly know how the weighted PAV algorithm works, but I don't want to insert the rough description into my article. I just want to give some reference. But I could not find any suitable description of weighted PAV simple enough to be understandable by non-mathematicians, best of all — in the form of some pseudocode.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

A couple of years ago I wrote an article about isotonic regression. Below is the link to the description of PAVA.

http://stat.wikia.com/wiki/Isotonic_regression#Pool_Adjacent_Violators_Algorithm

If $a$ is vector of input values, $w$ is vector of weights, $y$ is vector of output values minimizing $\sum_i w_i (y_i-a_i)^2$ subject to $y_1\leq ...\leq y_n$, the algorithm is:

```
Set a'[1]=a[1], w'[1]=w[1], j=1, S[0]=0, S[1]=1
For i=2 to n do:
    j++
    a'[j] = a[i]
    w'[j] = w[i]
    while j>1 and a'[j] < a'[j-1] do
        a'[j-1] = (w'[j]*a'[j] + w'[j-1]*a'[j-1]) / (w'[j] + w'[j-1])
        w'[j-1] += w'[j]
        j--
    S[j] = i
for k=1 to j do
    for l=S[k-1]+1 to S[k] do
        y[l] = a'[k]
```

Here S defines to which old points each new point corresponds.

Comment: As it stands this is more suitable as a comment than an answer. Could you give an outline of the algorithm here, please?

Comment: Ok, I did it. Also, fixed an bug on my page.

Comment: I think the code needs a `w'[j] = w[i]` to go with the `a'[j] = a[i]`.